# What is this prolog output trying to say?

Tags: prolog

Years ago in college,I tinkered with some prolog, but that's long forgotten, so I count as a complete beginnner again (humbling!)

Anyway, I was playing with some of Bruce Tate's code, and came up with what I thought was a sudoku solver for the full (9x9) game. But, when I run it, it generates some very odd output:

```
Solution = [_#3(2..3),_#24(2:7),_#45(2..3:5:7),_#66(2..3:8),_#87(2..3:5..6:8),4,_#121(2:5..6),1,9,6,8,_#194(2..5:7:9),_#215(1..3:9),_#236(2..3:5:9),_#257(1..2:5:9),_#278(2:4..5),_#299(4:7),_#320(5:7),_#341(1..2),_#362(2:4),_#383(2:4..5:9),_#404(1..2:9),_#425(2:5..6:9),7,3,_#472(4:6),8,4,1,_#532(2:8),_#553(2:8),7,3,9,5,6,7,5,_#689(6:8),_#710(4:8..9),_#731(4:6:8..9),_#752(6:8..9),1,2,3,_#828(2..3),9,_#862(2..3:6),5,1,_#909(2:6),7,8,4,8,_#990(2:4:7),1,6,_#1037(2..5:9),_#1058(2:5:9),_#1079(4..5),_#1100(3..4:7),_#1121(5:7),5,_#1163(4:6..7),_#1184(4:6..7),_#1205(1:3..4:8),_#1226(3..4:8),_#1247(1:8),_#1268(4:6:8),9,2,9,3,_#1341(2:4:6),7,_#1375(2:4..5:8),_#1396(1..2:5:8),_#1417(4..6:8),_#1438(4:6),_#1459(1:5)]

yes
```

I was expecting ... well, frankly I was half expecting total failure :) but I thought that only numbers could show up in this output. What's it trying to tell me with those #-tagged things, and stuff in parens that looks like ranges? Is it trying to say there are many possible solutions and it's telling me all at once (seems unlikely as it's very unhelpful if it is) or is this some kind of error state (in which case, why does it compile my code and say "yes" to this query?)

Any insight gratefully received!

Comment: You are using GNU Prolog.

Comment: Yes, gnu prolog 1.3.0. Is there a significance to that that I'm missing?

Comment: Somewhat; Other systems like SICStus or SWI show you these answers such that you can paste them back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's the result of a set of constraints not sufficiently strong to determine a solution without search. For instance, `_#3(2..3)` could means that a variable named `_#3` could assume values in range `2..3`. You could try to **label** the variables, something like

```
..., labeling([], Solution).
```

Syntax details depend on your solver, of course...

Comment: Hmm, I was rather afraid this could go in directions I'm not ready for :) That said, I _think_ I understand your comment to be broadly agreeing with my thought that this is telling me a range of answers are possible?
Meanwhile, more info that might be of use
1) I'm using gnu prolog 1.3.0,
2) your syntax results in "no"
3) "normally" (i.e. with simpler queries that behave in the way I expect) the searching seems to result in multiple outputs, and I can select "the next one" by pressing semicolon after the first one is presented, or I can type the letter 'a' and get them all.

Comment: @TobyEggitt read the section of the GNU Prolog manual discussing finite domains.

Comment: Thanks all, the manual page was more reference than descriptive, but I inferred enough to think I see what's happening. It seems it's trying to tell me the, potentially discontinuous, ranges that are plausible for each of those cells. In effect the particular problem I presented it had more than one solution.
So it seems that something triggered this behavior (instead of the more familiar "here's one possible" followed by "show me another" using semicolon or a. Perhaps that's because I had an fd_domain(...) in the code. Also, when trying to hand-code without FD, it just didn't work.THX